EcoProject1EcoSpace suddenly not instantiating in VS2022 (MDriven Framework, 4.8.1)
OK, so I solved this problem (runtime crash due to incompatible types recognized by Eco's TypeLibrary-scan).
Solution: I removed Rhinol3D classes from Eco method signature parameters, and then everything works again.
I got MDriven Framework 4.8.1 up running, and instantiated the EcoSpace successfully and used ConsoleApp (.NET Framework) to write some object data from the created classes. Everything was fine for hours when suddenly, after the last class (MLine) was added, the project stopped working at "new EcoProject1EcoSpace(...)". EcoSpace suddenly failed to instantiate.
At first I got a runtime error from what seems a faild attempt to instantiate the Eco type system, like so:

After reinstalling everything (including the EcoCore & Eco.SqlServer nuget packages) I now get a different error message when strying to instantiate the EcoSpace:

The following code used to work when all this happened.
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ecoSpace = new MCo.EcoProject1EcoSpace
    {
        Site = null,
        Active = false,
        PersistenceMapper = null,
        AllowDeactivateDirty = false,
        DefaultLinkFetchStrategy = FetchStrategy.FetchObjects,
        OptimisticLocking = false,
        UpdateWholeObjects = false,
        EnforceStringLength = false,
        EnsureSingletonInstancesOnEachEcoSpace = true
    };
    ecoSpace.Active = true;

My solution contains a ConsoleApp project and the EcoProject ("MCo") project (plus an enpty stub of a Rhino3D Grasshopper project, which was not changed and has no references to the Eco-project.

Could the problem be due some error in the UML model, since the problem started after adding a new class (MLine), although I can't see any visual clues about anything wrong with the model.
Checking the Model doersn't indicate any model errors:

What should I try (after having tried to reinstall everything Eco-related) in order to remedy the failed instantiation of the EcoSpace/system?
[EDIT]: I tried removing the class "MLine", and then the project was back running again. But when adding any new class to the model it will again fail to instantiate the EcoSpace. So the Model seems to have an internal problem somehow. I've tried re-indexing" the model, but problem remains. How can I track down the problem, or "clean" the model as to make it accept new classes again. I'm only on 6 classes so far (after removing MLine), and no more than 3 levels of inheritance.
Hopefully someone can help med find a way out of this showstopper.

I've now redrawn the entire model, but I still get a NullReferenceException from the "typeSystemProvider == null" test in GetTypeSystemService(). No indication of what is wrong. Checkling the UML Model doesn't indicate any model problems.

Hm. When using classes from RhinoCommon (API) I get runtime errors from "InstallMethodInfo" in the file OclTypeMethodInstaller.cs. BUT if I declare my own C# types (with similar names like Point3d, Vector3d, Plane & Line being used in the signatures of my Eco classes), then the Eco model runs fine. It seems the InstallMethodInfo somehow examines the classes being used and as the RhinoCommon classes contains strange stuff like "RenderMaterial" etc (not referred to by me) the InstallMethodInfo seems to go bananas.  Does this mean that classes containing unknown types can't be used in signatures?

The runtime crash was due to incompatible types recognized by Eco's TypeLibrary-scan of the model at runtime.
Solution:
I removed any Rhino3D classes from Eco method signature parameters. After that everything works in runtime again.
